# Cannot destructure property 'titulo' of 'actividad' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `useParams` hook to get a custom component. It renders the id, but nothing else. Below is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"; 
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import '../assets/css/Styles.css';
import '../assets/css/Colecciones.css';
import actividades from '../files/infoActividades.json';

function Acti() {
  const { actId } = useParams();
  const actividad = actividades.find((actividad) => actividad.id === actId);
  const { titulo, descripcion, deadline, etiqueta}  = actividad;

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className="header">
          <Link to=".." relative="path">
            <button className="btn-header">
              Regresar
            </button>
          </Link>      
          <h1 className="h1Contenido" style={{ fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue' }}>
            Desarrollo Web
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div className='main' style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
          <div className="actiCont">
            <div className="actiCont" style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
              <h1>{actId}</h1>
              <h2>{titulo}</h2>
              <p>2021-10-10</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style={{ height: '300px' }}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default Acti;
```

Comment: What exactly should you expect to be rendered and what do you mean when only the id is being rendered?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The returned `actividad` is undefined and can't be destructured from.

One, or both, of a couple issues are at play in your code:

1. Route path params are ***always*** a string, so using strict equality, e.g. `===`, in the `Array.prototype.find` callback function should be compared a string value in the array elements. If `actividid.id` is a number type, it can never be equal to a string type.
2. `Array.prototype.find` potentially returns `undefined` if no array element is matched by the predicate function. The UI component could should handle this case.

## Solution

1. Use a type-safe comparison by converting `actividad.id` to a string, if necessary.

   ```
   const { actId } = useParams();
   const actividad = actividades.find(
     (actividad) => String(actividad.id) === actId
   );
   ```
2. Guard against undefined accesses. This can be done several ways.

   - Provide a default object to destructure from:

     ```
     const actividad = actividades.find(
       (actividad) => String(actividad.id) === actId
     );
     const { titulo, descripcion, deadline, etiqueta } = actividad ?? {};
     ...
     ```
   - Check if `actividad` is defined and conditionally return early some fallback UI:

     ```
     const actividad = actividades.find(
       (actividad) => String(actividad.id) === actId
     );

     if (!actividad) {
       return <div>No Actividad</div>;
     }

     const { titulo, descripcion, deadline, etiqueta } = actividad;
     ...
     ```
   - Use the Optional Chaining operator on potentially undefined accesses:

     ```
     const actividad = actividades.find(
       (actividad) => String(actividad.id) === actId
     );

     ...

     <h2>{actividad?.titulo}</h2>
     ```

Complete example:

```
function Acti() {
  const { actId } = useParams();
  const actividad = actividades.find(
    (actividad) => String(actividad.id) === actId
  );

  const { titulo, descripcion, deadline, etiqueta } = actividad ?? {};

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="header">
        <Link to=".." relative="path">
          <button className="btn-header">
            Regresar
          </button>
        </Link>      
        <h1 className="h1Contenido" style={{ fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue' }}>
          Desarrollo Web
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div className='main' style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <div className="actiCont">
          <div className="actiCont" style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            <h1>{actId}</h1>
            <h2>{titulo}</h2>
            <p>2021-10-10</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style={{ height: '300px' }}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Acti;
```